# Using Unwind and Dumping Data in neo4j - Query Optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am doing **batch insertion** to insert data in **neo4j** but my transaction is taking huge time as my database is increasing continuously also.

In my project, For only one case ,I am having more then **18,000 records** which are meant to be stored in db and will have relationships with a Target node.
Each record will be stored as **Friend Node**

Relationships are like

**Target_Node-[r:followed_by]->Friend_Node**

**Target_Node-[r:Friends_with]->Friend_Nod**e

**Target_Node-[r:Performs_Activity]->Friend_Node**

My query executes for all the cases separately and the chances are very likely that there maybe all three relations between a Target and Friend Node.

I am sending 20 records per thread for a single insertion which unwinds over the array of records and checks if the records is already exists in Friend_Node or Target_Node, if not then create it as a Friend_Node and then assign relation to it; If the node already have relationship and a new relation is passed to the query then a new relation will also be added between the two nodes.

Also I do check in my query if a Record do have a **Location** property then I do create a Location Node and assign the relation with that also.

**Note**: create_rel variable can be Friends_with,Followed_by or Activity_p

My **query** is as follows

```
 """UNWIND [{id: "1235" , uid : "0"}] as user

    UNWIND """+ l +""" as c

    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Target {id : c.id , uid : "0"})

    OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Friend {id : c.id , screen_name:c.screen_name, uid : "0"})

    WITH coalesce(n, m) as node,user,c // returns first non-null value

    CALL apoc.do.when(node is null, "MERGE (n:Friend {id:c.id, name:c.name, profile: c.profile, location:c.location, uid : user.uid}) RETURN n", '', {c:c,user:user}) YIELD value

    with coalesce(node, value.n) as y,user,c

    MERGE (u:Target {id: user.id , uid : user.uid})

    """+create_rel+"""

    foreach (sc in c.cityn | merge(cn:Location {location:sc.location, loc_lower : sc.loc_lower}) merge (y)-[:`located_at`]-(cn))

    """
```

Db sometimes gives TransientError error also.

Feedback is appreciated as I am a learner and will appreciate valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem lies in how you merge and match the nodes. Ideally, you always want to have a unique identifier for nodes. I can see that `Friend` node has a property `id`, which I will assume is unique for every `Friend` and `Target`.

First, you want to create a unique constraint on that property:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:Friend) ASSERT f.id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:Target) ASSERT f.id IS UNIQUE;
```

You want something similar for `Location` nodes as well. seems like you store both location value and the lowercase value of location, so any of them should be unique for each node.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l:Location) ASSERT l.id IS UNIQUE;
```

Now you can optimize your query like this:

```
"""UNWIND [{id: "1235" , uid : "0"}] as user

    UNWIND """+ l +""" as c

    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Target {id : c.id})

    OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Friend {id : c.id})

    WITH coalesce(n, m) as node,user,c // returns first non-null value

    CALL apoc.do.when(node is null,
    "MERGE (n:Friend {id:c.id}) 
     ON CREATE SET n+= {name:c.name, profile: c.profile, 
           location:c.location, uid : user.uid} 
     RETURN n", '', {c:c,user:user})
    YIELD value
    with coalesce(node, value.n) as y,user,c
    MERGE (u:Target {id: user.id , uid : user.uid})
    """+create_rel+"""

    foreach (sc in c.cityn | 
        merge(cn:Location {location:sc.location}) 
        ON CREATE SET cn.loc_lower = sc.loc_lower 
        merge (y)-[:`located_at`]-(cn))

    """
```

Comment: I am creating indexes on the basis of id but unique constraint is not possible in my scenario. The reason is that my software may have a Friend node exists in system and later on user want to change this to be a target so constraints check fails as I am replicating the node in this scenario and changing only user id in this case(if I need it to be else no need) .. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your graph schema

Answer (score 0):

1. You should avoid running multiple write queries (that can touch the same nodes and relationships) concurrently, as that could cause intermittent `TransientError`s, as you have seen. (However, queries that cause transient errors *can* be retried.)
2. You should be passing `user` and `l` to your query as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), so that the Cypher planner will only need to compile the query *once*, and to make the query less prone to Cypher-injection attacks. (Also, there is no need to `UNWIND` a list that will always have just a single map -- you could have directly used the map via `WITH {id: "1235" , uid : "0"} AS user`. But, as I mentioned, you should just pass the `user` map as a parameter so you can efficiently change the user without forcing a recompilation.)
3. To avoid recompilation, you also need to need to make the `create_rel` string a constant string (so, it might as well be directly in your main query string). Again, you should also pass any variables needed by that as parameters.
4. You should create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) (or uniqueness constraints) on `:Target(id)` and `:Friend(id)`, to speed up your `MATCH` and `MERGE` clauses.
5. (a) `MERGE (u:Target {id: user.id , uid : user.uid})` only needs to be executed *once*, not per `c` value. So, it should be executed *before* the `UNWIND`.

   (b) Also, it is not strictly necessary for this query to create `u`, since nothing in the query uses it. So, instead of running this identical `MERGE` clause once per thread, you should consider taking it out and running it a separate standalone query.

Here is a query that combines suggestions #2 and #5a (but you will have to take care of the others yourself), along with some refactoring using [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to avoid unnecessary DB hits:

```
MERGE (u:Target {id: $user.id, uid: $user.uid})
WITH u
UNWIND $l as c
WITH u, c, [(n:Target {id : c.id})-[*0]-()|n] AS nodeList
WITH u, c, CASE WHEN SIZE(nodeList) = 0 THEN [(n:Friend {id : c.id})-[*0]-()|n] ELSE nodeList END AS nodeList
CALL apoc.do.when(SIZE(nodeList) = 0, 'MERGE (n:Friend {id: c.id, name: c.name, profile: c.profile, location: c.location, uid: user.uid}) RETURN n', 'RETURN nodeList[0] AS n', {c:c,user:$user,nodeList:nodeList}) YIELD value
WITH u, c, value.n AS node
FOREACH (sc IN c.cityn | MERGE (cn:Location {location: sc.location, loc_lower: sc.loc_lower}) MERGE (node)-[:located_at]-(cn))

// Put your parameterized create_rel code here
```

Comment: thanks for very nice suggestions; its really helpful. could you please add create_rel parameterized code also in query as I am bit confused with assigning the relationship at this point.

Comment: looking forward for your kind suggestion on this

Comment: I cannot add the appropriate parameterized `create_rel` code, because your question never showed the original `create_rel` code. I am just saying that you should try to NOT insert a separate `create_rel` string into this query -- you should just try to include whatever is in that string directly in this query. Without knowing what is in that string, I cannot tell you how to do that. And you may need to create a separate question if you need help with that eventually. This question is already way too complicated.